# How Do I Implement If-Statement within Method?

Tags: iphone, if-statement, methods, indexing, conditional-statements

Im a noob to iphone development and I am having trouble implementing an if-statement within the didSelectIndex method of AwesomeMenu.  The method fires and returns the value of the index selected, but it doesn't respond when I attempt to use the index in a conditional statement within the method.  For example, my log only prints "Select the index : 0", but not "Index 0". This is very frustrating to say the least.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

MY CODE:

```
- (void)AwesomeMenu:(AwesomeMenu *)menu didSelectIndex:(NSInteger)idx{

  if (idx==0) {

    NSLog(@"Index 0"); //Doesn't print

  }else if(idx==1){

    NSLog(@"Index 1"); //Doesn't print

  }else{

      NSLog(@"Else Block test"); //Doesn't print

  } 


NSLog(@"Select the index : %d",idx); //<--This Works.

}
```

Comment: So what does it print?

Comment: It only prints "Select the index : 0", but not "Index 0".

Comment: And that is honestly your whole code? You don't accidentally reassign idx or have something else in there that would cause this?

Comment: I see nothing wrong with this. Are you sure this is really what is being called? What happens if you do an else statement after the if else block?

Comment: That's simple, since you're using `else if` means idx is neither `0` or `1` but something else. If you put a `breakpoint` in either of the `if` or the `else if` I assure you it won't enter.

Comment: Set a breakpoint on the first line of this method, and examine idx when execution stops.

Comment: it a typo or your mistake that you have `]` instead of `}` to close else statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The delegate is simply set incorrectly.**

The boilerplate code for Awesome Menu includes the NSLog statement that is being called. Your above code is fine. You are simply not setting the delegate for the menu to the appropriate object. As a result, **your above code never runs.**

If you need assistance in this matter, please post the code demonstrating how you initialize your AwesomeMenu.

In any case, search your entire project for the phrase "Select the index" and you will find the delegate method ***that is actually being executed instead of your current code.***

Comment: I set the delegate for AwesomeMenu in my AppDelegate, like so.

menu = [[AwesomeMenu alloc] initWithFrame:self.window.bounds menus:menus];
menu.delegate = self;

And in my current class access it, like so..

GSCCAppDelegate *appDelegate = (GSCCAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[appDelegate.self.window addSubview:appDelegate.menu];

Is this incorrect?

Comment: And where is your above code? What is the name of the file/class it is in?

Comment: You need to place the above method (with your if/else statement) **in the same file** in which you write `menu.delegate = self;` You are currently putting it in the wrong file.

Comment: Go to your `CSCCAppDelegate` file and search for the words "Select the index". You already implemented it. Just search that phrase.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
NSInteger i = 2;
NSInteger j = 2;
if (i == j) { 
 NSLog(@"equal")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with your `If - else` statement. check your `(NSInteger)idx` closely.

Its working fine

`[self AwesomeMenu:nil didSelectIndex:1]`;

```
- (void)AwesomeMenu:(id )menu didSelectIndex:(NSInteger)idx{

    if (idx==0) {

        NSLog(@"Index 0"); //Doesn't work

    }else if(idx==1){

        NSLog(@"Index 1"); //Doesn't work

    }

    NSLog(@"Select the index : %d",idx); //<--This Works.

}
```

**Output**

```
Index 1
Select the index : 1
```